# Проблема с капчей для телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Суть капчи в том, что надо найти запрашиваемый смайлик из меню Inline кнопок, если выбрать неверный, то меню со смайлами перемешается и надо заново выбрать, если выбрать верный то бот скажет, что ты прошел капчу.
Если запустить код первый раз, то после выполнения команды /start все работает идеально, однако если второй раз нажать /start и попытаться пройти капчу, то появляется проблема: запрашиваемый смайлик сохраняет значение переменной предыдущего запрашиваемого смайлика, но бот не показывает этого и когда выбираешь из меню смайлик, то бот сверяет его с запрашиваемым смайлом из самой первой капчи ну и пишет что это неверно, вот полный код:

```
import random
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from config import MAIN_BOT_TOKEN


bot = Bot(token=MAIN_BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


emojis = ['','','','','','','','⬜️','⬛️']


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):

    correct_emoji = random.choice(emojis)

    shuffled_emojis = generate_captcha()
    keyboard = create_keyboard(shuffled_emojis)

    await message.answer(f"Найдите смайлик {correct_emoji}", reply_markup=keyboard)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Найдите указанный смайлик, чтобы продолжить.")

    @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: True)
    async def process_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):

        if callback_query.data == correct_emoji:
            await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, "Верно!")
            await bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, "Вы прошли проверку на капчу!")

        else:
            shuffled_emojis = generate_captcha()
            keyboard = create_keyboard(shuffled_emojis)

            await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, "Неверно! Попробуйте еще раз.")
            await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback_query.message.chat.id, message_id=callback_query.message.message_id, reply_markup=keyboard)

def generate_captcha():
    shuffled_emojis = random.sample(emojis, len(emojis))
    return  shuffled_emojis

def create_keyboard(shuffled_emojis):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for i in range(0, len(shuffled_emojis), 3):
        row = [InlineKeyboardButton(text=emoji, callback_data=emoji) for emoji in shuffled_emojis[i:i+3]]
        keyboard.row(*row)
    return keyboard



if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

Через отладчик заметил что переменная correct_emoji(запрашиваемый смайл) меняется на значение из первой капчи на этой строке:

```
async def process_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
```

Comment: Ну первое что бросается в глаза так это - хендлер в хендлере. По логике вещей это не даст вам ожидаемого результата. Т.е. структуру кода придется переписывать =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой вариант:

```
import random
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token="t")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

emojis = ['','','','','','','','⬜️','⬛️']

#Создаем кнопки (по старинке простите)
def created_kbr(emj):
    button_list = [] #для того, что бы сработал row_width, знаешь как лучше сделай.
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)    
    random.shuffle(emj)
    for item in emj:
        button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(text=item, callback_data=item)) #callback такой же как и текст, для последующего упрощения поиска верного ответа.
    keyboard.add(*button_list)
    return keyboard

@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start_msg(message:types.Message):
    #Тут же выводим сообщение, и через рандом цвет который нужно выбрать.  
    await message.answer(f'Выбери: "{random.choice(emojis)}"', reply_markup=created_kbr(emojis))

@dp.callback_query_handler(text = emojis)
async def checked_correct(cq: types.CallbackQuery):
    #сплитуем наш текст исходя из сообщения... cq.message.text.split = ['Выбери: ', '', ''] наш цвет первый элемент [1] ->
    capch_color = cq.message.text.split('"')[1] 
    if(cq.data == capch_color):
        await cq.message.edit_text('Верно! Capcha пройдена')
    else:
        await cq.message.edit_text(f'Другой цвет! "{random.choice(emojis)}"', reply_markup=created_kbr(emojis)) #Принцип тот же,что и со старта

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотелось бы добавить, что handler'bI никогда не используются внутри других handler'ov(по крайней мере года 2 назад так и было, может, что поменялось ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ ). Лучше немного скорректировать вашу логику и пользуясь документацией писать более лаконично.

Comment: не так элегантно как хотелось бы. но работает.